# Chrome continues crashing after restart

Tags: google-chrome

When Chrome crashes - in my case hangs due to an inadvertent developer mistake - I am unable to get the browser to load another page again unless I restart the server.
If I close the tab or even quit the browser it tries to start again where it left off and try to finish the process it started, which means more hanging. The only way I can get this going again is to restart the server.
Although if I open a new Incognito window it works, I guess due to it not having any connection to the crashed session.

Is there any way to force end this session other than a server restart?

Comment: Sounds like it's trying to reload the page that was displaying when it crashed. Try disabling the option that resumes old pages after restarting.

Comment: I guess that would solve it, shame though as it's a nice feature to have.